# Deleting google maps markers when stored in object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to populate a Google Map with markers from locations stored in a database and then allow the user to delete any of the markers by double clicking the marker to be removed. Using the code below populates the map but when any of the markers are double clicked the last marker is removed.

I assume this is happening because the double click event listener is being reassigned each time to the current marker but I can't work out how to stop this happening.

I have a jsFiddle set up here http://jsfiddle.net/simonbarker/TA4HP/

```
var markers = {"locations": [{"name" : "UK 1", "date" : "Nov 1", "lat" : 51, "lng" : 0.164},
                               {"name" : "France 1", "date" : "Nov 2", "lat" : 50, "lng" : 0.164},
                               {"name" : "France 2", "date" : "Nov 2", "lat" : 49, "lng" : 0.164}]
                };

  var map;
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(markers.locations[1].lat,markers.locations[1].lng);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  createMarkers();


  //create markers by traversing throught the markers object
  function createMarkers(){

    var i = 0;
    while(markers.locations[i]){

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers.locations[i].lat, markers.locations[i].lng),
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: map
      });

      //store marker in the locations object
      markers.locations[i].marker = marker;

      //add delete handler
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function(event) {
        marker.setMap(null);
        delete markers.locations[i];
      });

      i++;

    }
  }​
```

Any help would be great

**UPDATE:**

I solved this by changing the delete handler function to

```
//add delete handler
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function(event) {
            this.setMap(null);
            delete markers.locations[this.id];
          });
```

and adding an id to the marker when creating it

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              id: i, 
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers.locations[i].lat, markers.locations[i].lng),
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              map: map
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your markers in a separate function to obtain closure

Same answer as [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355249/how-to-create-infowindows-for-multiple-markers-in-a-for-loop/12355458#12355458)

[**Explanation here.**](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/closure.htm)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - it was feeling a bit like a dereferencing issue (I had even tried solving it by throwing in a & before the variable name) and that explains why. Thanks for the link, I found another way round it but yours is neater I think

Comment: Note that the answer you accepted is API V2 and will not work with the API V3.

Comment: And that would be because in my haste I accepted the wrong answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Store the objects in an array or dict so that you can reference them later with [this line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453297/how-to-delete-a-marker-on-google-maps) to remove them...

```
map.removeOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link - mapOverlay didn't work but I saw he was using "this" in his delete function. I tried that and it works.Thanks!

Comment: The removeOverlay() method is from the old V2 API, which is deprecated. In V3 you use marker.setMap(null)